# What is the easiest way to convert a custom time format to timestamp in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime

I have a data set with the time field in the format below:

```
29052016:09:01
```

Can anyone share with your easiest way to convert it into datetime in SQL Server?

Thank you very much.

Comment: at least you can tell us what does that string of numbers `29052016:09:01` represent ?

Answer (score 2):

Since you did not provide us any information on what is that string of numbers represent, i just have to make a wild guess that it represent `Year 2016 Month 05 Day 29 Hour 09 Minute 01`. And based on that, you can use `stuff()` to format it as `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm` then use `convert()` with style `103` to convert to `datetime`

```
declare @str varchar(20) = '29052016:09:01'

select  convert(datetime ,stuff(stuff(stuff(@str, 3, 0, '/'), 6, 0, '/'), 11, 1, ' '), 103)
```

If I totally make the wrong assumption, please ignore this answer.